# if output file from loop isn't empty, copy last line bash

Tags: bash

I have a loop, in a bash script. It runs a programme that by default outputs a text file when it works, and no file if it doesn't. I'm running it a large number of times (> 500K) so I want to merge the output files, row by row. If one iteration of the loop creates a file, I want to take the LAST line of that file, append it to a master output file, then delete the original so I don't end up with 1000s of files in one directory. The Loop I have so far is:

```
oFile=/path/output/outputFile_
oFinal=/path/output.final
for counter in {101..200}
do
    $programme  $counter -out $oFile$counter
    if [ -s $oFile$counter ] ## This returns TRUE if file isn't empty, right?
    then
        out=$(tail -1  $oFile$counter)  
        final=$out$oFile$counter 
        $final  >> $oFinal 
    fi
done
```

However, it doesn't work properly, as it seems to not return all the files I want. So is the conditional wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify the use of the $programme variable as well as the $phenotype variable in your if condition? Its hard to follow the logic as these two variables are not set.

Comment: This line: `$final  >> $oFinal` ... should that be `echo $final >> $oFinal`?

Comment: `$phenotype` should probably be `$counter` instead

Comment: yes it should sorry. I thought id changed all "phenotype" variables to counter to make this example easier to read. and $programme calls the programme.

Comment: Yes, id like $final to be sent to the $oFinal file. I stick the file name on it too (with $counter) , as its the easiest way I could come up with of recording which line comes from which iteration.

Comment: In your `then`, why not `echo -n $oFile$counter >> $oFinal; tail -1 $oFile$counter >> $oFinal;`?  That echos the file name with counter to the `$oFinal` log, followed by on the same line the last line of  that file.

Comment: if you are keeping all output files, you could just do `tail -n 1 /path/output/outputFile_*` after you run the loop.

Comment: the echo -n option is news to me. Awesome thanks! If you put it as an answer, Ill accept it

Comment: Does `$programme` have an exit code that indicates if it output anything? For example, 0 if it successfully outputs a file, 1 (or any non-zero) if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be clever and pass the programme a process substitution instead of a "real" file:

```
oFinal=/path/output.final
for counter in {101..200}
do
    $programme  $counter -out >(tail -n 1)
done > $oFinal
```

$programme will treat the process substitution as a file, and all the lines written to it will  be processed by tail

Testing: my "programme" outputs 2 lines if the given counter is even

```
$ cat programme
#!/bin/bash
if (( $1 % 2 == 0 )); then
    {  
        echo ignore this line
        echo $1
    } > $2
fi
$ ./programme 101 /dev/stdout
$ ./programme 102 /dev/stdout
ignore this line
102
```

So, this loop should output only the even numbers between 101 and 200

```
$ for counter in {101..200}; do ./programme $counter >(tail -1); done
102
104
[... snipped ...]
198
200
```

Success.